# ToggleButton drawable color not changing

Tags: android

On touching a ToggleButton, it's background color is not changing. The toggling does happen, confirmed by the changing text on touch. But the colour always remains white i.e. the unchecked state. What am i doing wrong?

ToggleButton :

```
<ToggleButton 
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:textOn="On"
            android:textOff="Off"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_day"
            />
```

It's background is a drawable toggle_day.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="oval"
    >
    <solid android:color="@color/toggle_day_bg_selector" />

</shape>
```

The color of the drawable is from a selector toggle_day_bg_selector.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/white"
        android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:color="@color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Try to **invert the logic**: use the selector directly in your ToggleButton and give the items 2 different shape objects, each with its own color.

Comment: For any newcomers, this issue was fixed for Lollipop and above, but older versions don't handle the color selector correctly for ToggleButton backgrounds. Using a selector rather than a shape as the background fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are set shape on toggle button that's why selector is not working.
set selector then it's work.

try this way

**ToggleButton :**

```
<ToggleButton 
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:textOn="On"
            android:textOff="Off"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_day_bg_selector"
            />
```

**toggle_day_bg_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_day"
        android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_daysecond"
        android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

**toggle_day.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="oval"
    >
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />

</shape>
```

**toggle_daysecond.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="oval"
    >
    <solid android:color="@color/holo_blue_dark" />

</shape>
```